# making a textview clickable in android

Tags: android

I am  making an android application,I have 4 textviews namely  ProductId,Title,description,image.I want when i click on each one of them product id should be displayed.I have a webservice for this.

Output of webservice is

```
vmsc>
<response code="0" message="Success"/>
−
<responsedata>
−
<productcategories>
−
<productcategory>
<id>1</id>
<title>Celebrities</title>
<description>Celebrities</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>2</id>
<title>Music</title>
<description>Music</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>3</id>
<title>Sports</title>
<description>Sports</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>4</id>
<title>Fashion</title>
<description>Fashion</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>5</id>
<title>Religion</title>
<description>Religion</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>6</id>
<title>Others</title>
<description>Others</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
</productcategories>
</responsedata>
</vmsc>
```

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created an xml with 4 texts..Here is my java code

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you want to define a ClickListener to each TextView, so it could, for example, display a toaster with the Product ID.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // request your webservice here. Possible use of AsyncTask and ProgressDialog
    // show the result here - dialog or Toast
  }

});
```

Answer (score 7):

> you can also do it using  xml like

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="handleOnClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Clickable TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

**and handle onClick  like**

```
public void handleOnClick(View view)
{
   switch(view.getId())
   { 
      case R.id.textView:
      //do your stufff here..
      break;
      default: 
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you do a "Long Click" in XML as well?

Comment: there isn't any build in method . But you can still customize your View to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13417824/3496570

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. Ended up using `setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {...}` in the Java Activity file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create `OnClickListeners` of your textviews like:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is a textview");

        textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something here.
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

this click listener works:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
TextView tvGmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGmail);
String TAG = "yourLogCatTag";
tvGmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View viewIn) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG,"GMAIL account selected");
                } catch (Exception except) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Ooops GMAIL account selection problem "+except.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

the text view is declared with no reference to `android:clickable="true"` (default wizard):

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu_id_google"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```