# Making to look TextView clickable, Android?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android and I have some doubts.

I have a `TextView`:

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go Back" />
```

how come I make the text `Go Back` look like clickable one? I'm asking in terms of look and feel. `TextView` should be shown as clickable as how `Button` getting rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means after click u want to change textview image if im right?????

Comment: It's duplicate question of this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537043/making-a-textview-clickable-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a xml file in your drawable folder called "mybutton.xml" and write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true">

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/mybutton2"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/mybutton1"/>

</selector>
```

Then add two png's into your drawables folder... mybutton1.png, mybutton2.png.
So you have 2 different states for your button.

Now set the background to your textview:

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
```

then, in your code you must set a clicklistener:

```
findViewById(R.id.mytextview).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    //your code goes here
 }

});
```

And that's all... You can use shapes instead of images too.

Answer (score 2):

For making your `TextView` `clickable` just add this to your `TextView`:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

after that you can set `onClickListener` to it by using this:

```
    yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do your work here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
// request your webservice here. Possible use of AsyncTask and ProgressDialog
// show the result here - dialog or Toast
 }

 };);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Touchlistener also:

```
textview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

just do this

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do your work here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a listener:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/needCheeseburger"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="getCheeseburger" />
```

And then just:

```
public void getCheeseburger(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, giveMeCheeseburger.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use like this `android:clickable="true"`

textview

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Large Text" />

text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope use full to u:-

```
boolean text_click =false;
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    public OnClickListener textOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (Constants.text_click) {
            textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbox);

            text_click = false;
        } else {

            textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textboxonpress);

            text_click = true;
        }

    }
};
```